# Read form fields from an image for OCR using java

Tags: java, image, ocr

I'm just extracting text from image but when I try to process form program doesn't work for character extraction due to form boundaries.  How to extract characters from a form which contains boundaries?

Comment: Show a scan/image of an example form.

Comment: Should I mail you image because my reputation count is low?please

Comment: Load it to an image sharing site and link to it.

Comment: http://www.ieeestudents.com/Form.jpg here is the form. Thank you

Comment: It should be possible to divide that form into sub-images along the long black lines.  If the *sub-images* are then supplied to OCR software, the result will come back in a way where you can divide & separate the parts of the form as required.

Answer (score 2):

Recognize the lines in the form , collect their positions in an array and write the image without considering values in the array using ImageIO.write